# How to send 2 parameters to useCallback in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to send 2 parameters to useCallback i do like this:

```
const Accounts = ()=> {
    
         const changeTextValue = useCallback((text, type) => {
                   setInfo((prevState) => ({
                                  ...prevState,
                                    Name: text,}));
                          },[])
    
    
                     <Form               
                        function={()=>changeTextValue(text,1)}
                      />
        
                     <Form               
                        function={()=>changeTextValue(text,2)}
                      />
            }
            
            
            
        
            const Form = React.memo((props) => {
              return (
                <FormInput
                  InputTextValue={props.function}
                />
              );
            });
```

when i type in first form, second form rerender again.

If i do like this:

```
     <Form               
        function={changeTextValue}
      />

     <Form               
        function={changeTextValue}
      />
```

it works but i cant send 2th parameter. How can i handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to destructure the params in the callback.

Try it this way:

useCallback({text, type}) => ...

Comment: problem is , i cant send second parameter here <Form               
        function={changeTextValue}
      />.  I shouldnt use like this :    <Form               
        function={()=>changeTextValue(text,type)}
      />

Comment: Have you tried using a Handler. Allow me to explain myself: HandlerFunc = (text, type) => { const changeTextValue = useCallback((text, type) => ...}

Answer (score 0):

Just define the functions and use them:

```
const changeFunc1 = ()=> changeTextValue(text,1)

const changeFunc2 = ()=> changeTextValue(text,2)

<Form               
  function={changeFunc1}
/>
        
<Form               
  function={changeFunc2}
/>
```